# JAVA Heap size doesn't grow more than 15GB

Tags: java

Although I'm using JVM parameter `-Xms32768M -Xmx65536M`
Maximum heap size is only 13.93GB at starting, (I checked it with `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`)
and does not grow any more than 15GB.

My program (It uses Multi-threading) is dead with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error` when the size of heap is about to exceed 15GB

My machine setting is as below:

Ram: 64GB,
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit,
Java Version: 1.7.0_79

Could anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: What JRE are you using?

Comment: Do you _have_ more than 15 GB available?

Comment: "*Could anyone tell me what is the problem?*" Not without more details. What OS are you using? Is it 32- or 64-bit? How much RAM does your system have?

Comment: @RealHowTo I'm using Java 7

Comment: @Patrick Roberts, Yes, I have

Comment: @QPaysTaxes, I've edited my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of ignoring JVM parameters....

I've put JVM parameters after a program arguments.

(e.g. java -jar my_prog.jar -prog_arg1 -prog_arg2 -Xms32768 -Xmx65536)

It was my mistake and I could solve the problem by putting JVM parameters ahead of program parameters...